# With lid closed, Macbook still occasionally wakes from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management

I've written some logging software in Electron which runs on macOS. I handle the `suspend` and `resume` events to stop and start recording automatically when the device is closed/suspended. I've noticed that even with the lid closed, it still wakes up occasionally and records some data. Does anybody know what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen only while plugged in, or does it also happen on battery? Under System Preferences > Energy Saver > Power Adaptor tab have Wake for Wi-Fi network access selected? Have you done an SMC reset recently? - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Power Nap?  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032

Comment: This occurs on my personal Mac and on 2 others we use for testing. For mine at least I've noticed its done it on battery when I've been on a flight.

Comment: Although reading the Power Nap docs it says `Computers with 2013 or a later year in the model name use Power Nap until the battery is drained`